# VS2019 C++ Error C2280 Attempting to reference a deleted function inl

Tags: c++

I'm and entry level in C++. Trying to build a project which wasn't created by me. After plugging a few missing libraries I'm stuck with C2280 error: 'CBrush::CBrush(const CBrush &)': attempting to reference a deleted function'. I'm confused on how to start getting to the bottom of the issue.

```
static COLORREF ClrList[] = { RGB(128,0,0),         // Red
                          RGB(128,128,0),       // Dark yellow
                          RGB(0,200,0),         // Green
                          RGB(0,200,200),       // Cyan
                          RGB(0,0,255),         // Blue
                          RGB(125,42,249),      // Purple
                          RGB(255,128,0),       // Orange
                          RGB(0,0,0) };         // Black

static CBrush BrushList[] = { CBrush(ClrList[0]),   //Error 2280
                              CBrush(ClrList[1]),
                              CBrush(ClrList[2]),
                              CBrush(ClrList[3]),
                              CBrush(ClrList[4]),
                              CBrush(ClrList[5]),
                              CBrush(ClrList[6]),
                              CBrush(ClrList[7]) };
```

CBrush Class declaration:

```
    class CBrush : public CGdiObject
{
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC(CBrush)

public:
    static CBrush* PASCAL FromHandle(HBRUSH hBrush);

// Constructors
    CBrush();
    CBrush(COLORREF crColor);             // CreateSolidBrush
    CBrush(int nIndex, COLORREF crColor); // CreateHatchBrush
    explicit CBrush(CBitmap* pBitmap);          // CreatePatternBrush

    BOOL CreateSolidBrush(COLORREF crColor);
    BOOL CreateHatchBrush(int nIndex, COLORREF crColor);
    BOOL CreateBrushIndirect(const LOGBRUSH* lpLogBrush);
    BOOL CreatePatternBrush(CBitmap* pBitmap);
    BOOL CreateDIBPatternBrush(HGLOBAL hPackedDIB, UINT nUsage);
    BOOL CreateDIBPatternBrush(const void* lpPackedDIB, UINT nUsage);
    BOOL CreateSysColorBrush(int nIndex);

// Attributes
    operator HBRUSH() const;
    int GetLogBrush(LOGBRUSH* pLogBrush);

// Implementation
public:
    virtual ~CBrush();
#ifdef _DEBUG
    virtual void Dump(CDumpContext& dc) const;
#endif
};
```

Im not familiar with inl files, but I assume this is inline declaration:

```
_AFXWIN_INLINE CBrush::operator HBRUSH() const
    { return (HBRUSH)(this == NULL ? NULL : m_hObject); }
_AFXWIN_INLINE CBrush* PASCAL CBrush::FromHandle(HBRUSH hBrush)
    { return (CBrush*) CGdiObject::FromHandle(hBrush); }
_AFXWIN_INLINE CBrush::CBrush()
    { }
_AFXWIN_INLINE CBrush::~CBrush()
    { }
_AFXWIN_INLINE BOOL CBrush::CreateSolidBrush(COLORREF crColor)
    { return Attach(::CreateSolidBrush(crColor)); }
_AFXWIN_INLINE BOOL CBrush::CreateHatchBrush(int nIndex, COLORREF crColor)
    { return Attach(::CreateHatchBrush(nIndex, crColor)); }
_AFXWIN_INLINE BOOL CBrush::CreateBrushIndirect(const LOGBRUSH* lpLogBrush)
    { return Attach(::CreateBrushIndirect(lpLogBrush)); }
_AFXWIN_INLINE BOOL CBrush::CreatePatternBrush(CBitmap* pBitmap)
    { return Attach(::CreatePatternBrush((HBITMAP)pBitmap->GetSafeHandle())); }
_AFXWIN_INLINE BOOL CBrush::CreateDIBPatternBrush(const void* lpPackedDIB, UINT nUsage)
    { return Attach(::CreateDIBPatternBrushPt(lpPackedDIB, nUsage)); }
_AFXWIN_INLINE BOOL CBrush::CreateSysColorBrush(int nIndex)
    { return Attach(::GetSysColorBrush(nIndex)); }
_AFXWIN_INLINE int CBrush::GetLogBrush(LOGBRUSH* pLogBrush)
    { ASSERT(m_hObject != NULL);
        return ::GetObject(m_hObject, sizeof(LOGBRUSH), pLogBrush); }
```

Comment: What does this macro DECLARE_DYNAMIC(CBrush) mean?

Comment: The error message means that the compiler sets the copy constructor of the class CBrush as deleted. And in this initialization static CBrush BrushList[] = { CBrush(ClrList[0]),, ... }; there is used the copy constructor.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cobject-class?view=msvc-160#remarks-2), you need to add a copy constructor for the `CBrush` object.

> The standard C++ default class copy constructor does a member-by-member copy. The presence of the private CObject copy constructor guarantees a compiler error message if the copy constructor of your class is needed but not available. Provide a copy constructor if your class requires this capability.